# Jquery - animate height toggle

Tags: jquery, height, jquery-animate, attr

I have a 10px bar along the top of the screen that, when clicked, I want it to animate to a height of 40px and then if clicked again, animate back down to 10px. I tried changing the id of the div, but it isn't working. How could I get this to work, or is there a better way to do it?

body html:

`<div id="topbar-show"></div>`

css:

```
#topbar-show { width: 100%; height: 10px; background-color: #000; }
#topbar-hide { width: 100%; height: 40px; background-color: #000; }
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#topbar-show").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:40},200).attr('id', 'topbar-hide');
  });
  $("#topbar-hide").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:10},200).attr('id', 'topbar-show');
  });
});
```

Comment: Please do not change the id of the element. Please do toggle a class i.e. <div id="top-bar" />, $("#topbar").toggleClass('hidden');

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#topbar-show").toggle(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:40},200);
  },function(){
    $(this).animate({height:10},200);
  });
});
```

Comment: It wasn't. I just took longer to type mine up and submit it. (All of the answers came in between when I viewed the question and submitted my answer.)

Comment: Note that this kind of toggle has been deprecated since jQuery 1.9.1, and will not work as it once did. For versions >= 1.9.1, [something along these lines will work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4965040/1813830)

Answer (score 19):

You should be using a `class` to achieve what you want:

css:

```
#topbar { width: 100%; height: 40px; background-color: #000; }
#topbar.hide { height: 10px; }
```

javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#topbar").click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('hide')) {
        $(this).animate({height:40},200).removeClass('hide');
      } else { 
        $(this).animate({height:10},200).addClass('hide');
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Very easy to implement, Thank you for contribution.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [`toggle-event`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) method to assign 2 (or more) handlers that toggle with each click.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/SQHQ2/1/

```
$("#topbar").toggle(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:40},200);
},function(){
    $(this).animate({height:10},200);
});
```

---

or you could create your own toggle behavior:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/SQHQ2/

```
$("#topbar").click((function() {
    var i = 0;
    return function(){
        $(this).animate({height:(++i % 2) ? 40 : 10},200);
    }
})());
```

Comment: +upvote : @user113716 : can u plz explain in details (2nd solution)

Answer (score 3):

Very late but I apologize. Sorry if this is "inefficient" but if you found all the above not working, do try this. Works for above 1.10 also

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var position='expanded';

    $("#topbar").click(function() {
      if (position=='expanded') {
        $(this).animate({height:'200px'});
        position='collapsed';
      } else {
        $(this).animate({height:'400px'});
        position='expanded';
      }
    });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

That would be a possibility:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#topbar").toggle(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:40},200);
  }, 
  function(){
    $(this).animate({height:10},200);
  });
});
```

```css
#topbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="topbar"> example </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: how i do this to go from height 10 to height 100%

Answer (score 2):

The below code worked for me in jQuery2.1.3

```
$("#topbar").animate('{height:"toggle"}');
```

Need not calculate your div height,padding,margin and borders. It will take care.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought to give you the reason why your solution did not work:

When `$(document).ready()` is executed only the `$('#topbar-show')` selector can find a matching element from the DOM. The `#topbar-show` element has not been created yet.

To get past this problem, you may use live event bindings

```
$('#topbar-show').live('click',function(e){});
$('#topbar-hide').live('click',function(e){});
```

This is the most simple way to fix you solution. The rest of these answer go further to provide you a better solutions instead that do not modify the hopefully permanent id attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this trick:
replace

```
$("#topbar").click(function(){
```

by

```
$(document).on("click", "#topbar", function(){
```

This will bind an event on a not loaded yet object...
;)

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

```js
$(".filter-mobile").click(function() {
   if ($("#menuProdutos").height() > 0) {
      $("#menuProdutos").animate({
         height: 0
      }, 200);
   } else {
      $("#menuProdutos").animate({
         height: 500
      }, 200);
   }
});
```