# rdio Player Footer Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Im trying to recreate the script that rdio (http://rdio.com) has created for their player footer. when you click on footer, a panel slides up nicely and to reveal more content. another example is by teehan lax; the top dropdown http://www.teehanlax.com/ but theirs doesn't support firefox properly.

I came across this snippet, http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/dddropdownpanel.htm
But its not clean as rdio's or teehan.

any thoughts on library they might using?

Answer (score 0):

We're just using basic CSS transitions, and adding and removing classes.  The z-index of the bottom bar is set such that it appears in front of everything else, and the class changes control how the content is changed.

You can accomplish the same height changes with jQuery quite easily, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4965097/1309238