# Toggle masonry image height by set number of pixels on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

Let me know if the title of this query is unclear. The below code excerpt instead makes the clicked image disappear.

I have reviewed [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477360/toggling-height-of-div-in-jquery) that toggles an element's height between a set number of pixels. I have reviewed Desandro's [masonry toggle](https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html) code. And I have reviewed the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). Nonetheless I'm struggling to realise a solution.

I appreciate that this may be simple to experts but for a novice some direction would be appreciated.

i_stack

```js
$grid.on('click', '.grid-item', function() {
  $(this).toggle(
    function() {
      $(this).height($(this).height() + 100);
    },
    function() {
      $(this).height($(this).height() - 100);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: I think this has a wrong logic, as the [Toggle documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) doesn't accept 2 functions. The first parameter is expected to be the duration in ms. I think you should use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead.

Comment: Thanks Dimitris. I considered the toggleClass but struggled to apply it to my particular problem. Fortunately, Andy's answer seems to work below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is meant to completely hide or show an element:

> Description: Display or hide the matched elements.

Instead, consider [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) using your own toggle logic.

```js
var counter = 0;

$('.grid').on( 'click', '.grid-item', function() {
  // counter will toggle between 0 or 1
  let direction = ++counter % 2 === 1 ? "-=100px" : "+=100px";
  $(this).animate({ "height": direction }, "slow" );
});
```

```css
.grid-item {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qxb10rnv/

Comment: Thank you kindly, Andy - I was really battling. There's a complication in my design (I have overlays on the imgs to which I'll apply your code, but presumably that'll only work after reconfiguring the masonry so that it arranges the overlays rather than images) but I'm optimistic I'll be able to adapt your solution. Thanks again, i_stack

Comment: In case of interest, the extension mentioned in my previous comment was simpler than anticipated - the code was adjusting grid-item heights on click but not rearranging the masonry to show this. The below code fixes this:

   var counter = 2;

   $grid.on( 'click', '.grid-item', function() {
      let direction = ++counter % 2 === 1 ? "+=100px" : "-=100px";
       $(this).animate({ "height": direction }, "slow", function(){
        $grid.masonry('layout')
       } );
   });